# Format date with SheetJS

Tags: javascript, xlsx, sheetjs

Thank you in advance for taking a look at this question! I am trying to use SheetJS to read a .xlsx file but am having some trouble with a column of dates that is formatted via Excel as Custom "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss".  All of these dates show up as large float values.

Here is the code to read the .xlsx file on upload:

```
uploadWorkbook(e) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(e.target.files[0]);
    reader.onload = (e) => {
        let data = e.target.result;
        let workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
        let first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
        let worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
        let jsonObj = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);
        console.log(jsonObj);
    }
}
```

As an example, the first object's date value is 43395.29775462963.  I would even be okay with formatting all cells as strings if this is possible.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

So, I figured out that passing the raw option when converting the sheet to JSON outputs all cells as a string. So it would be:

```
let jsonObj = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {raw: false});
```

Comment: I use {raw: false} for sheet_to_json function, but the data ''12/21/1989" turns to be"12/12/89" and "12/21/2019" turns to be "12/2119". Auto trims the year part. Could you give some tips to fix it?

Comment: i'm having a similar issue, not sure of a fix either.

Comment: Did u get a solution to this @greenie @Evan?

Comment: Same issue, it does not work

Comment: you can use moment to reformat the date
`moment(date_field, 'MM/DD/YY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')` - this turns 11/30/21 into 2021-11-30

Answer (score 34):

This is my way:

```
 const target = e.target.result;
 const wb = XLSX.read(target,{type:'binary',cellText:false,cellDates:true});
 const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
 const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
 const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {header:1,raw:false,dateNF:'yyyy-mm-dd'});
```

Comment: Nice, this is what I've been looking for!

Comment: Tried this but I'm getting date in format mm/dd/yy instead of mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: For those who want use dots: `{dateNF:'yyyy"."mm"."dd'`} ref: https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/718#issuecomment-313465344

Answer (score 24):

I'm not pretty sure if back then these flags existed, but currently (December 2019), you can add the flag "cellDates" in order to have it as a date instead of a number.

```
const workbook = XLSX.read( data, {
    ...
    cellDates: true,
});
```

And this is better since the data type is now a date in a date format instead of a string in a date format.

Comment: I think this is a better solution to handle date fields.

Comment: What about the time zone? I'm getting the date of next day than in the sheet @Leon

Comment: Best solution, should be accepted answer

Comment: The question is how to set the format for such output. It returns Date object with full time zone and other 'unnecessary stuff'. How to make it output dd/mm/YY H:i:s only?

Answer (score 7):

xlsx file data in JSON object with date format you can try with below example

```
reader.onload = function(e) {
    var data = e.target.result;
    var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
        header: 1,
        raw: false,
        dateNF: 'dd/MM/yyyy'
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < workbook.SheetNames.length; i++) {
        var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[i]], {
            header: 0,
            raw: false
        });
        Console.log(XL_row_object;)
        break;
    }
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(files);
```

Comment: This works like a charm to me. Adding dateNF in XLSX.read function helps to read the dates properly. Thanks @Sid55813

Answer (score 5):

**e.target.result** was giving me undefined for data. Below solution worked for me. Check this out.

```
 onFileUpload($event) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString($event.target.files[0]);
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      const target = reader.result;
      const wb = XLSX.read(target, { type: 'binary', cellText: false, cellDates: true });
      const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
      const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 0, raw: false, dateNF: 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss' });

      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, applied the same code as @Charles G

```
onFileChange(event) {
        this.file = event.target.files ? event.target.files[0] : null;

        var data = new Uint8Array(this.file)
        
        const  reader = new FileReader();

        if (data) {

            reader.onload = (e) => {
                /* Parse data */
                console.log('Parse data');
                const bstr = e.target.result;
                const wb = XLSX.read(bstr, {type:'binary',cellText:false,cellDates:true});
                /* Get first worksheet */
                console.log('Get first worksheet');
                const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
                const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
                /* Convert array of arrays */
                console.log('Convert array of arrays');
                const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {header:1,raw:false,dateNF:'yyyy-mm-dd'});
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            }

            reader.readAsBinaryString(this.file);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If reading data by cell.
For example. `worksheet['A1'].v`

Instead of .v use .w to get the raw data.
So use `worksheet['A1'].w`

Wasted a lot of time figuring it out in my project.

Answer (score 0):

```
const element = document.getElementById('excel-table');
const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(element);
```

in "ws" date format like a this json

```
{
  "t": "n",
  "v": 44933.000555555554,
  "z": "m/d/yy"
}
```

so we know date have type (t) number (n) and z is "m/d/yy"

```
Object.keys(ws).forEach(cell => {
      const cellValue = ws[cell];

      if (cellValue.t === 'n' && cellValue.z === 'm/d/yy') {
        const excelDate = cellValue.v;
        const jsDate = new Date((excelDate - (25567 + 1)) * 86400 * 1000);
        const formattedDate = `${String(jsDate.getDate()).padStart(2, '0')}.${String(jsDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0')}.${jsDate.getFullYear()}`;
        ws[cell].v = formattedDate;
        ws[cell].t = 's';
      }
    });
```

and do `const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();`...